# I used edge wallet to send my bitcoin from my wallet to my cash app but i used a low fee soo its been unconfirmed for 10 days what can i do?

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

My transaction 5c8552a6744b3428d3ec4b5c0dd8b378ffeb4efd703b76a2b9d106250234d766
Has been unconfirmed for 10 days is there anything I can do to get it confirmed or do I just have to wait?

Answer (score 0):

ViaBTC's Transaction Accelerator service can be used and you can pay with BTC but it will cost $100 or more.

You can wait for your transaction to be confirmed by Monday or you could have tried to spend unconfirmed UTXO if it was not cash app and some non custodial bitcoin wallet by following the below steps :

1. Generate a new Bitcoin address in wallet.
2. Make sure RBF (Replace By Fee) is ON. Send some or all of the unconfirmed balance (from the parent) to that address.
3. Copy the new transaction ID (TX ID) and paste it in the 'Child TX ID' field here: https://cpfp.djbooth007.com/
4. Enter the desired sats/vB amount. This can be determined by looking at the range of sat/vB in recently confirmed blocks or mempool stats on https://mempool.space
5. Click 'Calculate Fee'
6. Perform RBF (Replace By Fee) with the calculated result highlighted as 'Child to Pay'.

Other things you can use in future is RBF for every transaction and a change address if possible.

Some open source bitcoin wallets that support RBF:

```
Bitcoin Core
Electrum
Bluewallet
Sparrow
Wasabi
Green
```